# Building a function to count leading zeros in a string with no success

Tags: python, function, for-loop

This is what I came up with:

```
def leading_zeros_counter(x: str):
    zeros = 0
    for i in x:
        if i == str(0):
            zeros += 1
        else:
            return int(zeros)
```

It seems to work on all strings unless the string contains all zeros (e.g. '0000' does not return '4'). Can anyone explain why and how to fix this?

Comment: Think about what lines of your function are reached when every character is zero. If you can't do it in your head, use a debugger or e.g. https://pythontutor.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `return` statement out of the `if` condition:

```
def leading_zeros_counter(x: str):
    zeros = 0
    for i in x:
        if i == "0":
            zeros += 1
        else:
            return zeros
    return zeros
print(leading_zeros_counter("0000"))
```

So the output would be:

```
4
```

Comment: Small hint: You don't need `return int(zeros)` because `zeros` is already an integer. A simple `return zeros` is enough.